# Json Parsing in Android in list view

Tags: android, mobile

Anyone know of any examples to dynamically load Json data into a ListView, most examples I have seen just use a static array of some kind. I need to load say 10 rows of Json data, then at the bottom have a load more.. to get the next 10 etc etc. Examples using Json please....

Comment: try with link : http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Comment: I am beginner on android. Please dont vote down it. If you cant help thats fine

Comment: To make things really easy, you can use the gson library with a custom adapter to populate a listview, if you are ok with using external libs

Comment: What budget do you have? I'll do it for you... Otherwise show us your attempts, your trials

Comment: Thanks Varsha, Please vote my question I already lost my points :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link, it's very well explained: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Comment: Just FYI, answers with link only are frowned upon, as the link can go dead.